# Delphi How to use custom font my application on android?

Tags: android, delphi

I m on **Delphi XE7**, and I want to use a custom font in my application on **Android**. But I didn't find yet a way to do it. How to do?

Comment: http://community.embarcadero.com/index.php/blogs/entry/true-type-font-iconography-for-android-and-ios-apps

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar On a side note, that article says "...and has to match the file name of the font file..." If I'm not mistaken, that is wrong - it's supposed to be the *name* of the font, which can very likely differ from the *filename*...

Comment: @JerryDodge I never actually tried to use custom font on android, so I don't know whether article got something wrong or not.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I replied to the post to point it out.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar but in this article they ask to update the delphi source file (FMX.FontGlyphs.Android.pas) and it's sound like crazy for me ! and just copying and updating FMX.FontGlyphs.Android.pas not work because this file have also dependancies :(

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
//Typeface := TJTypeface.JavaClass.create(FamilyName, TypefaceFlag);
FontFile := TPath.GetDocumentsPath + PathDelim + CurrentSettings.Family + '.ttf';
if FileExists(FontFile) then
  Typeface := TJTypeface.JavaClass.createFromFile(StringToJString(FontFile))
else
  Typeface := TJTypeface.JavaClass.Create(FamilyName, TypefaceFlag);
```

Comment: See if it helps:    http://www.tdevrocks.com.br/2015/09/17/tutorial-usando-fonte-customizada-no-android/

Comment: This seems to assume that the user has placed the font file manually into their documents directory.

Comment: yes but it's sound crazy that we must update the delphi original source file to do this !! :(

Comment: more it is obvious that you will not change the original file from Delphi, it is very simple, you make a copy of that file and add in your project folder and then change ...

Comment: no this is a very bad practice in general, for exemple the file FMX.FontGlyphs.Android.pas is not the same in seattle, so updating source file is a very a bad practice because it's (can) make migration very painfull :(

Comment: Hardly "very bad practice". It's usually pretty straightforward to re-patch when a new version comes out. Takes me about 2 hours at most, for about 20 or so changes.

Comment: this not working for me , font exists in `.\assets\internal` but not assigned to objects!